# Set your app to detect and open when a specific link is clicked - Xcode, Swft 4

Tags: ios, swift, ipa

I'm currently working on an iOS app, Swift 4, that automatically launches on click of a link to block users from accidentally navigating to that link.

How would I set this up?

For example, YouTube opens up youtube.com links.

Sorry if this is a vague question, if more info is required feel free to ask ^^

Comment: If you control the domain that you are trying to "block" then you can set up a universal link to open your app if installled, but you cannot intercept arbitrary links.

Comment: Ohhh, ok thanks. That should be an answer. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you create a custom URL protocol like `myapp://somepath` (where `myapp` is the protocol) then you just register that custom protocol, and when the user clicks such a link it’ll automatically open your app. You can’t intercept a general purpose URL protocol like HTTP or YouTube.

(At least not without OS support. That's how YouTube and the app store are able to open HTTP links.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything like this so far but it seems like you should take a look at Apple URL Scheme and Universal Links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq/ios-custom-url-scheme

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection?utm_source=raywenderlich.com%20Weekly&utm_campaign=95f29cf4fc-raywenderlich_com_Weekly5_31_2016&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_83b6edc87f-95f29cf4fc-415182745